# Pure HTML document apparently has some JavaScript running in the background in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, javascript

I had to make asimple Pure HTML Document with no CSS and no JavaScript, to see how some Unicode Characters look like.

While viewing this Document in Mozilla FireFox, it showed the Unicode Characters and I left the tab open for a long time. When FireFox was overloaded by too many tabs, it showed a popup that this particular tab was hung:

> Warning: Unresponsive script

Details were:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Now, my Document did not have any script tag, so I was surprised to see this popup on this tab. Even more surprising was the Script Path shown in the popup:

> Script: resource://activity-stream/vendor/react-dom.js:188

Path seems to be seems to be internal to FireFox.

I tried to access this Path and `resource://activity-stream/vendor/` and `resource://activity-stream/;` there seems to be a lot of content.

Is this expected behavior? Why did FireFox include a script in my pure HTML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any plugins installed in Firefox? Many times plugins and add-ons would make a call like that.

Doing a [basic Google search for `resource://activity-stream`](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22resource://activity-stream/%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) makes me believe it’s this add-on for Firefox called [Activity Stream](https://github.com/mozilla/activity-stream).

> This system add-on replaces the new tab page in Firefox with a new design and functionality as part of the Activity Stream project.

Comment: +1 , Somehow, my SuperUser Inbox showed 2 new messages, which I assumed was for the "question edit" and the "comment" ; I seem to have missed your answer ! Also, this is a system addon which means it is an integral part ; Probably we can not disable that.